# Do differential backup in simple mode and log backup in full mode protect db to the same extend?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

I think log backup in full mode and deffiential backup in simple mode do the same protection. I know log backup can do more, like point in time restore, I am talking about how recent I can restore my db to with these two method.

For example, I do full backup weekly, differently daily at 24:00 and log backup hourly. And my db crushed at 05:30.
so, I can restore db from full backup, differential backup and log backup from 24:00 to 05:00.

however I can run db in simple mode, and do a differentical backup hourly, so I can restore my db from weekly full backup and all diff backup up to 05:00.

so seems both them can restore my db to 05:00, am I right? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both differential and log backups provide the same recovery point if you don't consider point-in-time recovery. You'll be able to restore to the point the most recent differential backup in the `SIMPLE` recovery model or, in the `FULL` or `BULK_LOGGED` model, to the point the last transaction log backup was made.